# Add gridlines to an Excel sheet

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

In the below code, how can I add grid-lines to the entire Excel sheet?

```
    Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    objApp.Visible = True
    Set wb = objApp.Workbooks.Open("template.xls", True, False)
    wb.Sheets(1).Rows(3).Delete
    wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = title
    'need to format column E & F as currency

    Set objApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the long answer (the code Excel VBA generates when you record a Macro).  You can definitely shorten this up.  For instance, you don't need to set the .ColorIndex or .TintAndShade properties just to do a standard black [edit] **border**.

```
Cells.Select
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
```

**EDIT**

For gridlines:

```
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True
```

you can also use:

```
Windows(1).DisplayGridlines = True
```

Comment: That is for borders, grid-lines are something else... Thank you though!

Comment: How would I use the border code with this code below (I'm having trouble referencing Cells.Select):                                                          `Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objApp.Visible = True
    Set wb = objApp.Workbooks.Open("template.xls", True, False)
    wb.Sheets(1).Rows(3).Delete
    wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = title`

Comment: If .Select does not work, you can use Range instead:  Range(myRange).Borders(...etc...  If you want to do the whole sheet that way, myRange would be "A1:XFD1048576", depending on your version of Excel.

Comment: `Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")       objApp.Visible = True  Set wb = objApp.Workbooks.Open("\\bk00sql0002\template.xls", True, False)  
wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = title  
objApp.Cells.Select  
objApp.Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone  
objApp.Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone  
With objApp.Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)  
.LineStyle = xlContinuous  
.ColorIndex = 0  
.TintAndShade = 0  
.Weight = xlThin  
End With  `

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True
```

That should turn the gridlines on. And, of course, setting the property to `False` will turn them off.